tell if a directory exists in one of the prefixes
I'm trying to find a way to detect if a directory exists in one of the CMAKE prefix.
I am integrating a recipe in yocto, and a program tries to check is a directory exists to activate or not a feature.
The problem is that it looks for a path like /usr/include/somelib, but this does not exist on the system, but exists in the build/tmp/work/corei7-64-rdos-linux/MyApp/git/recipe-sysroot.
When working with standard libraries, this works fine because cmake is able to search for things relative to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH using the Config.cmake files.
The function find_path works well with files (it crawls the prefixes), but does not accept a path (with /).
Is there a way to do that with cmake?

Just iterate over the variables you want (e.g. foreach(dir_prefix ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}), construct full path of the possible directory (e.g. set(dir ${dir_prefix}/usr/include/somelib) and check directory existence (with if(IS_DIRECTORY ${dir})).

IIUC, you can add option to enable/disable that lib on Yocto recipe too. Adding DEPENDS  on Yocto recipe makes sure that lib is a dependency.
